# Is it bad to store "JSON.stringify" data in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I can't choose between SQLite and SharedPreferences.

I can use

```
JSON.parse(SharedPreferences.getString("data","qweqwe");
```

and

```
s.putString(key,JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
```

Or create a new, big class to store my (text) data in SQLite. (PS: JSON.* is my own class)

What will be faster, better?

I know that SharedPreferences is for "key-value" data, SQLite - for big amount of structured data. But in my case storing JSON-formatted data in SP and accessing by key would be easier. Main question - will it be slower or faster? Pros and cons?

Comment: Looking forward to input from the community on this, as I have the same question on my mind.

Comment: @dotty my reasoning. About SQLite: I'll need to create new classes, I get JSON data from URL and with SQLite I'll need to write twice as much code to use this data. About SharedPreferences: I load data from URL, s.putString this data without any manipulations, where I do use JSON.parse I can just: JSON.parse( s.getString("jsdata","qweqwe").equals("qweqwe") ? JSON.get(url) : s.getString("jsdata","qweqwe")) and a few functions to update / manipulate with this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about this and had some practice.

So, using SQLite (in my case) is better that using JSON-formatted string in SharedPreferences, because I can just update only one-two rows from a table. With SharedPreferences I have to:

1. use `new JSONObject(sharedPreferences.getString("json_string","qweqwe");`
2. some manipulations with object
3. edit my SharedPreferences.
4. <s>seasoning to your taste</s>
5. Put my JSONObject().toString() back into SharedPreferences. It's all.

IMHO, it's more complicated for the device. <s>Because it cannot be seasoned</s>

If I wouldn't need to update an individual parts of data, I'd rather to use SharedPreferences, because for static data, which I don't need to update, is faster.

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand this is a slightly subjective question (and not the best fit for stackoverflow). On the other hand, taking your question title literally, the objective answer is "No, it's not *bad*".

The reasoning is, however, slightly subjective as it 'depends' on the situation.

The `SharedPreferences` class is effectively a wrapper / helper for a file stored in an app's private (internal) storage - as I understand it, it's an XML file. Based on that fact, ask yourself again..."Is it bad to save a JSON-formatted string in an XML file"?

As you mention in the commen on your question, using a SQLite database will mean writing extra code whereas the advantage of `SharedPreferences` is that a given preference file is accesible by name by any Android class which extends `Context` including `Application`, `Activity` and `Service`.

Comment: In desc I wrote more objective questions. :) e.g. what is more faster?

Comment: @anony_root : I'm afraid I don't have any benchmarks for which is faster and, again, that's still slightly subjective and something which would need to be properly tested. Saving a single short JSON string in either way might only have a few milliseconds difference. Saving hundreds (or thousands) of long strings may take a significantly different amounts of time. If you have simple requirements then `SharedPreferences` might be the way to go as the functionality is built-in to all `Context` based classes.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this approach in several projects without any issues so far.  But there are certainly several advantages to using an SQLite database; particularly, the versioning/upgrade features of SQLite, and the powerful SQL querying language.  If you ever need to migrate data to a new structure of storage, the upgrade and onUpgrade callbacks in the SQLite framework can be immensely helpful.

If you are keeping it simple, JSON in preferences can be very quick and extremely easy to implement.  In terms of security, preferences are slightly more "exposed" than a database in that they are simply stored in xml, but ultimately the database file for an SQLite database is stored the same way and can be read during an intrusion as well.

I haven't had any performance issues using JSON/SharedPreferences yet, but I also haven't done any profiling to test this.  My mindset has been to keep the code simple and not optimize prematurely - if performance issues arise, do the work of profiling it at that point.

Ultimately, I'd say that there is nothing inherently wrong with using SharedPreferences in this manner.